# import: I want script can be run by other file and also can be run directly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have some scripts(`app.py` and `app2.py`), I want them can be run by `main.py` in parent directory, and also can be run directly.

the project structure:

```
main.py
package
├── __init__.py
├── app.py
├── helper.py
package2
├── __init__.py
├── app2.py
├── helper.py
```

main.py

```
from package import app
from package2 import app2
```

package/app.py

```
from .helper import greeting

greeting()
```

package/helper.py

```
def greeting():
    print('hello')
```

package2/app2.py

```
from .helper import greeting

greeting()
```

package2/helper.py

```
def greeting():
    print('hello in package 2')
```

when I run `main.py`, it printed

```
hello
hello in package 2
```

it's correct, but I can't run `package/app.py` directly, it will throw error `attempted relative import with no known parent package`

One solution I found in stackoverflow is changing code inside `main.py` to:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'package')
sys.path.insert(0,'package2')

from package import app
from package2 import app2
```

then remove the dot in `app.py` and `app2.py`. Now I can them directly, but new issue is when I run `main.py`, it printed

```
hello in package 2
hello in package 2
```

which is wrong.

another solution is chaning `app.py` and `app2.py` to like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from helper import greeting
else:
    from .helper import greeting

greeting()
```

It solved all my problems, I just wonder is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__":`